# Typing lag issue in IntelliJ 10

Tags: performance, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ 10 commercial edition and recently I started experiencing a significant lag while typing anything in it. It got to the point where I need to wait 1-2 seconds for every characters to appear on the screen.

Some people online suggested uninstalling the "IntelliLang" plugin.
I did that and it didn't really help.

Here's the contents of my `idea.exe.vmoptions`

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-server
```

Answer (score 2):

Try IDEA [10.5 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+10.5+EAP). If the same issue remains, [provide a CPU snapshot](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192).

Such issues should be reported directly to [JetBrains support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/) or [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: I can't install any IDEA 10.5 EAP. I have to mind the corporate policy.

Comment: According to the customer e-mail this issue is resolved in IDEA 10.5.

Comment: I've experiecned the same thing. Resolved for me in IDEA 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you're using OpenJDK instead of Sun's. It dramatically lowers Idea's performance.